# MySQL: Workbench can connect remotely, but nothing else

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL user called spock.  The user spock can connect from my Mac to my MySQL server with MySQL workbench with no problem.  I can get on, perform queries, and so on.  When I try to connect from Mac to MySQL with anything other than MySQL Workbench -- `mysqli_connect` in PHP, for example -- I'm told that access is denied for spock@10.0.0.105 (the Mac's IP address).

Why would spock be allowed to connect using Workbench and nothing else?

Edit: new layer.  It appears that applications running on my Mac can't connect to any remote MySQL server.  I can connect to localhost or 127.0.0.1 all night, but my Mac just won't talk to remote MySQL servers.

Comment: Womp womp.  He is busy getting more power to the warp drive.

Comment: Tried different ports?

Comment: 3306 is definitely the one.  I think otherwise MySQL Workbench would fail to connect on 3306.